# How to pass selected file from file upload button to slot props when using vue-csv-import?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, csv

So I'm making an app right now that's using a package called vue-csv-import and in the docs it tells me that I can define my custom element inside the `vue-csv-input` component it provides which exposes two slot props `v-slot="{file, change}"`. I've been clawing my eyes out trying to find a way for my code to work. I tried doing it like this but it doesn't work. It somehow can't find my uploaded file in my custom file input but the component works when I'm not defining a custom input and just use the default input the package provides. The package documentation has no examples on how to do actually use the slot props for a custom file input so I can't rely on that.

**MyComponent**

```
<vue-csv-input v-slot="{file, change}">
     <label for="finput" class="fancy-upload-btn">Upload CSV File</label>
     <input @change="change" type="file" name="file" id="finput">
</vue-csv-input>
```

**VueCsvInput from vue-csv-import**

```
<template>    
    <slot :file="file" :change="change">        
    <input ref="csvRef" type="file" change="change" :name="name" v-bind="$attrs">    
    </slot>
</template>
```

**What's inside the change function in VueCsvInput**

```
const change = function () { let tmpFile = csvRef.value.files ? csvRef.value.files[0] : null; 
    if (validate(tmpFile)) { VueCsvImportData.file = tmpFile;
    }            
}
```

I've tried ddding ref="csvRef" to my custom file input but doesn't work either. It always ends up not getting the uploaded the file and the package documentation has no examples on using it with a custom file input, only that it provides the props to do so.

Your help would be highly appreciated. If you have an alternative package to recommend then that would be nice too.

Comment: What is Vue's version?